# How would I make a function to dynamically determine if user is logged to change navigation menu text?

Tags: functions, customization, menus, navigation

I would like to create a function to determine if a user is logged in or logged out. If the user is logged in I would like the navigation menu text to say "My Account" (this is what it currently displays because 'My Account' is the page name.) If the user is logged out, I would like the navigation menu text to read "Login".

This is my idea so far....

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $my_account = "My Account";
    return is_page($my_account);
} else {
    $login = "Login/Sign Up";
    return is_page($my_account) = "$login";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with the `is_page` parts - maybe I'm missing something - but what if you'd just write:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $my_account = "My Account";
    echo ($my_account);
} else {
    $login = "Login/Sign Up";
    echo ($login);
}
```

`return` just returns the variables for use in your code,  `echo` prints them to the HTML